# Ruby on Rails database is not configured

Tags: ruby-on-rails

We have 2 Ruby on Rails websites. Live and Beta. Recently we made a database move, so I was asked to try and update the database connections for the websites. I did that using the `database.yml` files for both.

Afterwards, the Live website works as expected, but the Beta throws up an error:

```
 'staging' database is not configured. Available: ["defaults", "production", "writeable"] (ActiveRecord::AdapterNotSpecified)
```

My `database.yml` file:

```
defaults: &defaults
  adapter: mysql2
  host: eu-west-1.rds.amazonaws.com
  pool: 10
  reconnect: true
  encoding: utf8
  database: Project_database

production:
  <<: *defaults
  username: Username
  password: Password
  port: 3306

writeable:
  <<: *defaults
  username: Username
  password: Passowrd
  port: 3306
```

How do I solve this, without effecting the Live website?

Ruby 2.3.0
Gems 4.2.6

Comment: Does the production and beta servers share the same database?

Comment: Yes, they do, but they are setup as different applications.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add this with **appropriate** username and password to `database.yml` file.
Might be [helpful](https://richonrails.com/articles/creating-a-custom-rails-environment)

```
staging:
  <<: *defaults
  username: Username
  password: Password
  port: 3306
```

Comment: Well, I think most guess right, Username and Password text has replaced the actual username and password.  That is not the issue. I know that for certain given the other part of the site works fine, along with countless PHP sites.

Comment: Said, I am sorry, I miss read your recommendation. I did not notice the "staging" option. I will try that and see if that has any effect.